# Absolute change and percentage change.

Tags: absolute-value, percentages

[This](http://www.math.umb.edu/~joan/MATHQ114/change.htm) page says-
absolute change = new quantity – old quantity.

For ex-
Example 1:  On September 20, a gallon of gas at my usual gas station cost $1.83.  On September 30, I noticed that the price had gone down to $1.65 per gallon. 
The absolute change in the price of gas between September 20 and September 30 is

```
              1.65 – 1.83 = - 0.18 dollars per gallon
```

We say that the price of gas decreased by $0.18 (or 18 cents).
And this page also says

Percentage change =    absolute change/original quantity*100

Example 1 revisited:  On September 20, a gallon of gas at my usual gas station cost $1.83.  On September 30, I noticed that the price had gone down to $1.65 per gallon.

The percentage change in the price of gas between September 20 and September 30 is

(1.65 – 1.83) 100 = - 0.18(100) = -18% per gallon

We say that the price of gas decreased by 18% per gallon.

**But from the formula of percentage change I can see that they are not dividing it by origianl quantity.
Is this right?**

Please help me figure out.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. You'll notice in example 2 they do it correctly.

Comment: They also should not have said per gallon.

Comment: thanks... It was confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $\frac {1.65-1.83}{1.83}100\%\approx 9.8\%$  The definition you have quoted is clear.